# For loop in cli batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I've a bunch of videos that I need to batch remux with MKVtoolnix using cmd. For that I'm using this cmd. I'm not aware of how to run this cmd in loop.

This is the cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output ^"E:\Output\Video - 001.mkv^" --language 0:mul --track-name ^"0:Video - 001^" --display-dimensions 0:768x576 --language 1:hi --track-name ^"1:Video - 001^" --language 2:ta --track-name ^"2:Video - 001^" --default-track-flag 2:yes --language 3:te --track-name ^"3:Video - 001^" ^"^(^" ^"E:\Batch\Video - 001.mkv^" ^"^)^" --attachment-name cover_small.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^"E:\cover\cover_small.jpg^" --attachment-name cover.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^"E:\cover\cover.jpg^" --attachment-name cover_land.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^"E:\cover\cover_land.jpg^" --title ^"Video - 001^" --track-order 0:0,0:2,0:3,0:1
```

As of now I'm doing like this

```dos
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output ^"E:\Output\Video - 001.mkv^" --language 0:mul --track-name ^"0:Video - 001^" --display-dimensions 0:768x576 --language 1:hi --track-name ^"1:Video - 001^" --language 2:ta --track-name ^"2:Video - 001^" --default-track-flag 2:yes --language 3:te --track-name ^"3:Video - 001^" ^"^(^" ^"E:\Batch\Video - 001.mkv^" ^"^)^" --attachment-name cover_small.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^"E:\cover\cover_small.jpg^" --attachment-name cover.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^"E:\cover\cover.jpg^" --attachment-name cover_land.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^"E:\cover\cover_land.jpg^" --title ^"Video - 001^" --track-order 0:0,0:2,0:3,0:1

"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output ^"E:\Output\Video - 002.mkv^" --language 0:mul --track-name ^"0:Video - 002^" --display-dimensions 0:768x576 --language 1:hi --track-name ^"1:Video - 002^" --language 2:ta --track-name ^"2:Video - 002^" --default-track-flag 2:yes --language 3:te --track-name ^"3:Video - 002^" ^"^(^" ^"E:\Batch\Video - 002.mkv^" ^"^)^" --attachment-name cover_small.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^"E:\cover\cover_small.jpg^" --attachment-name cover.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^"E:\cover\cover.jpg^" --attachment-name cover_land.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^"E:\cover\cover_land.jpg^" --title ^"Video - 002^" --track-order 0:0,0:2,0:3,0:1
```

.....etc

I need to run this command in a loop for n times

Comment: Why do you need to escape the opening and closing parentheses, and all of the doublequotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /a serial=1000
:again
set /a serial+=1
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" ...
if %serial% leq 1234 goto again
```

Then replace **each** `001` in your `mkvmerge.exe` line with `%serial:~-3%` which will then execute `mkvmerge.exe` with the last 3 digits of the serial number.

The loop will execute 234 times with `1234` set as the limit, `001`..`234`.

---

Here's the actual test file I created

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set /a serial=1000
:again
set /a serial+=1
ECHO "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output ^"E:\Output\Video - %serial:~-3%.mkv^"
if %serial% leq 1010 goto again
ECHO done...
GOTO :EOF
```

The first two lines simply suppress command-echoing and establish a local environment so that changes will be discarded when the batch terminates.

I truncated the `mkvmerge` line as the remainder should be more of the same, and `echo`ed it since executing it makes no sense on my system.

Without the `echo`, the `mkvmerge` should run.

This is the output I obtained.

```
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 001.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 002.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 003.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 004.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 005.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 006.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 007.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 008.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 009.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 010.mkv"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output "E:\Output\Video - 011.mkv"
done...
```

Comment: only the first video is muxed and then its shows E:\>if %serial% leq 1110 goto again. I've set the limit to 110 cuz I've only that much of vid in my directory

Comment: You need `1010` to limit the run to 10 (001..110). The limit needs `1000` to be added to it because anything less does not have 4 digits of which to select the last 3.

Comment: You do realise that this is a batch file, don't you. Cut-and-paste to an ANSI text file and save as *something*.bat Then execute `something` at the prompt.

Comment: E:\>if %serial% leq 1010 goto again Same error